# How do I report only checked fields in Gravity Forms?

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

Say I have list of 50 checkboxes in a field. I limit responses to 3.

Ex:

```
Apple = AP
Orange = OR
Pear = PE
etc.
```

How can I tell Gravity Forms to report only the checked boxes, like so:

```
First Choice: PE
Second Choice: AP
Third Choice:
```

It this possible through filters or or via the Gravity Forms API?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change how the field value is displayed on the entry detail page or when it's merge tag is output in notifications/confirmations? The default behaviour of the checkbox field in these locations is to only list the choices which were selected by the user.

Comment: The answer is that you have to write a customization using their API to do this.